# Custom TextInput and variable size in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, size, textinput

I want to create a custom textinput component in flex. The component is made of one background rectangle (spark.primitive.Rect) and one inside rectangle that will contain the text.

My problem is that I want my component to be sizable like I want. For example if I want to create one textinput with a size of 200/100 I write :

```
<s:TextInput x="10" y="10" width="200" height="100" skinClass="Component.MyTextInputSkin"/>
```

And I have only the width and height to change if I want to create another textinput with different size.

My skin mxml contains two rect but I want to do this:

```
<s:Rect width="{this.width}" height="{this.height}" .....
```

and for the other one (the one that will contain the text)

```
<s:Rect width="{this.width * 0.80}" height="{this.height * 0.80}" .....
```

The problem is that flashbuilder displays an error message of incompatibilty on my two "Rect" lines. And when I launch my app, nothing is displayed.

Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you usually create a skin based on default `TextInputSkin` from SDK and modify the parts you need.

[Since skins are very big I packaged the sample application in FXP.](http://www.mediafire.com/?2uzwn2pw9auxs3s)

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't understand the purpose of the overriding of udpatedisplay, commit function. I understand what they do but why change them. Can't we just create an adaptable skin without using these functions?

Comment: It's just a *default* skin with some minor changes. Feel free to remove any piece of AS code from it and see if it's OK for you.